# How to see the requests sent by LogStash to the elasticsearch output in Fiddler?

Tags: logstash, fiddler

I have `LS_JAVA_OPTS = -DproxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888`

And yet, I see no traffic to my elasticsearch node from logstash in Fiddler.

I know my elasticsearch is up and running. When I curl it, Fiddler clearly shows the requests, so it is something about `jruby` that does not route requests through Fiddler.

I am not calling `jruby` directly. Rather I use the `bin\logstash.bat` script.

**Appendix**

My conf file:

```
input {
    file {
        path => 'c:/log/bje-Error.log'
        sincedb_path => "NUL"
        codec => plain {
            charset => "ISO-8859-1"
        }
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} "
            negate => true
            what => previous
        }
        start_position => beginning
        ignore_older => 0
    }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \[%{BASE10NUM:thread:int}] %{WORD:machine}:%{WORD:service} \[%{BASE10NUM:localId:int}?:%{UUID:logId}?:(?<jobKind>[^:]+)?:%{BASE10NUM:jobDefinitionId:int}? %{WORD:namespace}?:%{WORD:job}?:(?<customCtx>[^\]]*)\] %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{NOTSPACE:logger} - (?<text>(?m:.*))" }
    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
        document_type => 'logs_bje'
        hosts => ["ncesearch01"]
    }
}
```

Testing in powershell:

```
PS E:\logstash-2.3.2\bin> (ConvertFrom-Json((Invoke-WebRequest "http://ncesearch01:9200/logstash-*/_count").Content)).count
24666
PS E:\logstash-2.3.2\bin> .\logstash.bat -f C:\dayforce\DayforceDEV\elk\logstach.conf
LS_JAVA_OPTS was set to [-DproxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888]. This will be appended to the JAVA_OPTS [ -XX:HeapDumpPath="$LS_HOME/heapdump.hprof"]
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 12
Pipeline main started
{
            "message" => "2016-05-02 16:00:05.7079 [111] CANWS212:MyBJE [2251:e2737eeb-40d6-4b0e-9608-75ee3de894d3:ScheduledInstance:16 DFUnitTest:BillingDataCollectionJob:] ERROR
SharpTop.Engine.BackgroundJobs.Billing.BillingDataCollectionJob - The client database version is not defined in DFDatabaseIdentification  \r",
           "@version" => "1",
         "@timestamp" => "2016-05-03T03:40:50.531Z",
               "path" => "c:/log/bje-Error.log",
               "host" => "CANWS212",
          "timestamp" => "2016-05-02 16:00:05.7079",
             "thread" => 111,
            "machine" => "CANWS212",
            "service" => "MyBJE",
            "localId" => 2251,
              "logId" => "e2737eeb-40d6-4b0e-9608-75ee3de894d3",
            "jobKind" => "ScheduledInstance",
    "jobDefinitionId" => 16,
          "namespace" => "DFUnitTest",
                "job" => "BillingDataCollectionJob",
              "level" => "ERROR",
             "logger" => "SharpTop.Engine.BackgroundJobs.Billing.BillingDataCollectionJob",
               "text" => "The client database version is not defined in DFDatabaseIdentification  \r"
}
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? ←[33mSIGINT received. Shutting down the agent. {:level=>:warn}←[0m
stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
Pipeline main has been shutdown
The signal HUP is in use by the JVM and will not work correctly on this platform

^CPS E:\logstash-2.3.2\bin> (ConvertFrom-Json((Invoke-WebRequest "http://ncesearch01:9200/logstash-*/_count").Content)).count
24667
PS E:\logstash-2.3.2\bin>
```

As you can see, `http://ncesearch01:9200/logstash-*/_count` returns incremented count, hence running logstash did send a request to the elasticsearch. However, it bypassed Fiddler, despite the LS_JAVA_OPTS.

Answer (score 0):

I find some possible reasons for this condition，although I did not try.May this answer should be called "discussion"，I`m sorry.

```
1.You may need a linux OS instead of windows，for the reason，
  I am not sure this question has been deal in the latest logstash version
```

you may be interested in this,[Make JAVA_OPTS and LS_JAVA_OPTS work consistently on Windows](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb)

```
2.As we see，the most possible is that
  logstash ES_output plugin use the http way to send message 
  after logstash-2.0,you may use the old version?
```

moreInfo about ES_output_plugin,[logstash-output-plugin-elasticsearch](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb)

If anyone has any ideas,your share will be expected~